# JQuery live search - populate input issue

Tags: jquery, html

My knowledge of JQuery/Javascript is very limited, and I'm having a small issue implementing a live search. Given an input field, once a user starts typing for something to search, a live search box will show possible results. If a user decides to click on one of the suggested fields, the clicked item will then be filled into the input box.

My issue is really weird. All is working except that the clicked suggested results don't register if clicked on the actual text or the image. The input box is populated only when the empty space of the suggested result's div layer is clicked. I need it so that the input box is populated no matter where the click is made on the suggested result.

HTML:

```
<input autocomplete=off name="search1" type="text" class="search1" id="searchid1"/>
<div id="result1"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".search1").keyup(function() 
    { 
    var searchid1 = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'search1='+ searchid1;
    if(searchid1!='')
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxsearch1.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#result1").html(html).show();
        }
        });
    }return false;    
    });

    jQuery("#result1").live("click",function(e){ 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#searchid1').val(decoded);
    });
    jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("search1")){
        jQuery("#result1").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });
    $('#searchid1').click(function(){
        jQuery("#result1").fadeIn();
    });
    });
```

Ajaxsearch1.php returns plain html. Pseudo code:

```
<div class="show>
<div style="float:left;>Thumb image here</div>
<div style="float:right;>Text here</div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**

> The live() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.7, and removed in
>   version 1.9. Use the on() method instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've moved to the on() method, but my issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#result1').on('click', '.show', function(e){
    var img_name = $(this).find('.name').html();
    $('#searchid1').val(img_name);
});
```

Instead of:

```
jQuery("#result1").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid1').val(decoded);
});
```

If that does not work, then there is an issue that is not coming through in your explanation. For example, your pseudo code does not include 'name' class anywhere?